# Map-like function to return multiple values on each iteration in the loop

Tags: list, stream, scheme, racket, map-function

Is there any sensible way of transforming this:

```
(for ([cos-t (stream-map cos t-range)]
      [sin-t (stream-map sin t-range)])
  ...)
```

to something like this:

```
(for ([(cos-t sin-t) (... t-range)]
  ...)
```

It's not really a map function, since you can't make a list that way. I'm just looking for better and easier way of doing the thing above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is already available using the `for` form.  Use the [`in-parallel`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-parallel#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._in-parallel%29%29) function to combine two sequences in this way:

```
(for ([(cos-t sin-t) (in-parallel (stream-map cos t-range)
                                  (stream-map sin t-range))])
  (displayln (+ cos-t sin-t)))
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but the link is pointing to your local documentation. <http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-parallel#(def._((lib._racket/private/base..rkt)._in-parallel))>

Comment: Silly me.  Thanks @MartinNeal and Danny.

Comment: Thank you. Nice to know that lots of things are included.